# Problem with Magento 2 and CloudFront AWS

Tags: magento2, cloudfront-cdn

I have a Cloud Front distribution that servers files from '/pub/static' folder of Magento.

This distribution has that configurations above:

[image]

[image]

[image]

But some files are broken because it's not on cloud front.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show error from browser console?

Comment: Hi @BartZalas I can't. But the error always appears after a deploy to production, because Magento append path version change to url.

Comment: Yes but cloudfront will download new version. Maybe your error is with cors policy? Without part error is difficult to help. Even your path with  pub/static could be an issue.

Comment: @BartZalas, there's no error in dev console....just a 404 not found page.

Answer (score 1):

> Origin path in Origin Settings
>
> leave it empty  (this is reason why you get error)

Default/root/object in Distribution Settings set to your path pub/static  (or static)

Allowed http methods set to GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE

After this changes , wait a little. You should load static files now or see 502 error (this mean you are on good road)

Update:

I just found this, really helped me:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/four-steps-for-debugging-your-content-delivery-on-aws/